# Is it okay to use past tense when writing about a fictional story?

Tags: north-american-english

When talking about a book, or a fictional story we are required to use present tense. The question is:

- Can we use past tense if it is a flashback?
- Also, can we use past tense like in the sentence below

> Rufus lives a fairly comfortable life compared to many people in his neighborhood, and he became a horrible person

Comment: You may use whatever combination of tenses you like.

Comment: There is no past tense in the example you give, so it's hard to answer whether you can use the past tense like in the example. I suppose the answer is yes: you can refrain from using the past tense just like in the example if you want to. Or was the example supposed to say _lived_ rather than _lives_?

Comment: Are you describing a story in which Rufus features? So you might say, "In this book, Rufus lives a fairly comfortable life..."? If so, just use whatever tense makes sense. If the story is that Rufus *had* lived such a life and had fallen on hard times, then the present tense in your sentence doesn't fit.

Comment: It would be unusual for a work of fiction to be written in anything other than the past tense. There is such a thing as the "historical present", and Thomas Carlyle managed a history of the French Revolution, all written in the present tense. But it would be unusual for a novel to be so written.

Comment: @Janus Bah Jacquet Ah yes, I have made a mistake in the quote. I have added "and he became a horrible person". I know this is a bad example so tell me if I made another mistake. :)

Answer (score -1):

I have read a short story in which the writer used *flashbacks*. The story is a letter for friend written in the present tense, but through the use of flashback, the events are represented in the past tense.

- The literary technique **flashback** is used to add some important details to the plot of the story; where the present time of the story is stopped or interrupted to remember something in the past. **So** I think you can use the past tense when you use flashbacks.